# Input mask doesn't work with decimal

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, webforms, jquery-inputmask

I'm using a jquery libary called inpunt mask, I have a problem with it when I loaded data inside the inputs, for example:

[image: imagen]

In the first image I put the data, I saved the data, when I want to show the data again, in the second image the inputs show me the information like this:

[image]

If I do inpect in html page the value in the first input shows me 2.2 (`value="2.2"`) but in the box shows me 22.

I want to save the data 2.2 and when I needed show the same (2.2 not 22.0).

### code

Assinging value to the input:

```
_vista.Temperature = (double)_vista.appointment.Temperature ;
```

When I'm debugin the value of `(double)_vista.appointment.Temperature` is 2.5, also I tried using hardcode, `_vista.Temperature = 2.5;` and is the same, dosen't work.

The controltextbox:

```
<cc:ControlTextBox runat="server" ID="txtTemperature" ValidationType="Number" AllowDecimal="true" DecimalPlaces="2" MaxLength="6"/>
```

when the browser rendere the input

```
<input name="ctl00$cphW$ucSoap$ucObjective$txtTemperatura" value="2.5" maxlength="6" id="cphW_ucSoap_ucObjective_txtTemperatura" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return onlyDigits(event, this.value,true,true,true,',','.',2);" size="8">
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        separador = ",";     
        $('#cphW_ucSoap_ucObjective_txtTemperatura')
            .inputmask("9{1,3}[" + separador + "9{0,2}]");
});
```

**(the input's value is 2.5 but in box shows me 25)**

Comment: when you write the values to the database what do you see when you debug it, and how are the values declared. 

please show your code to show what youre doing

Comment: JSfiddle it please